# Text in paragraph is only vertically centered in flexbox when omitting it's <p> tag, what's the reason behind it?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

When looking at the following Vuetify code

```
<v-layout align-center justify-center row fill-height>
        <v-flex xs1>
          <v-icon color="primary">clear</v-icon>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs8>
          <p>Text</p>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex>
          <v-btn rounded color="primary">Do Something!</v-btn>
        </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

(for more context:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNvzbQ)

"Text" is not vertically centered

But when replacing

```
<v-flex xs8>
          <p>Text</p>
</v-flex>
```

with

```
<v-flex xs8>
          Text
</v-flex>
```

it suddenly is.

I also could not center it with `align-items: center` or `align-content: center` in the surrounding div.

Whats the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: p has a default margin applied to it

Comment: Oh, that's it, thank you very much, I somehow managed to overlook that in the dev tools :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It IS actually centering the `p` tag. Like other's has pointed out. The `p` tag has a default bottom margin, so it just makes it look as if it's not centered vertically.

See below image, where the orange highlight is actually the bottom margin of the `p` tag.
Notice how it's actually vertically centered.

[image: P Tag]

So, you can fix this by either:

- Remove the `p` tag altogether like you said
- Use `div` tag instead, which doesn't have a margin
- Just set the style of the `p` tag to have `margin-bottom: 0`